# Suppress repeating Columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables:

- `bpoint` -> table of all houses
- `images` -> table of house images (max 3 per house).

Here is my MySQL join query to fetch a house information and it's images:

```
SELECT 
    bpoint.*, bimages.iURL
FROM
    bpoint,
    bimages
WHERE
    bpoint.pointID  = bimages.pointID
AND bimages.pointID = '$tocka'
```

Since there are more image rows than house rows (there is always only one house result and 1-3 image results), is there a way to drop house result doubles which come with every image?

Comment: did not get the question, you want to drop the result from bpoint table if for a single image multiple houses are there?

Comment: i'm guessing you want this for display proposes, and you still want the row, but do not want to repeat the house info.. correct?

Comment: @randy Correct! How can i achieve that?

Comment: maybe a title of 'Suppress repeating Columns' would be better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that, unless you use two separate queries. If there were a way, what would you expect the resultset to look like for, say, the second image of the first house?

Anyway, what I would do here is add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query, to make sure all images from the same house are in sequence. Then, on the PHP display loop you just ignore the house information if you already printed it from the previous row.

Comment: i agree with the solution as a PHP effort.  however - in oracle you could use a LAG function, or make a user defined aggregate function to suppress the values. (not sure if this translates to mysql)

Comment: @Randy I don't know Oracle, but I don't believe such a thing exists in MySQL. On your Oracle solutions, what would `bpoint.*` look like for repeated rows? Just a bunch of `NULL`s?

Comment: yes - typically you would replace the repeating value with a null.

Answer (score 1):

By using `GROUP BY` and a `JOIN` you can get the result you are looking for;

```
SELECT bpoint.*, bimages.url FROM bpoint
LEFT JOIN bimages 
       ON bpoint.id = bimages.pointId
GROUP BY bpoint.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/5d1fd/3/0